m3u8 video plays in Safari only
My video plays in Safari but not in Firefox and Opera.
in Firefox i get the message "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported."
in Opera, tries to start but it doesn't. In Firefox mobile, starts but stops immediately.
my page is here: http://mypaok.xyz/test.html
and this is the html code:
<head>
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.18.1/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.18.1/video.min.js"></script>

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <!-- <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls autoplay="true"
    preload="auto"
    width="1280"
    height="720"
    poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://gate1.mypaok.xyz:8081/hls/paok.m3u8">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>
</body>

when i try to open the stream link http://gate1.mypaok.xyz:8081/hls/paok.m3u8 with VLC plays normally..
can anyone help me ?
i stream with obs, and this is my nginx.conf (docker)
worker_processes auto;
rtmp_auto_push on;
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        listen [::]:1935 ipv6only=on;
        chunk_size 4096;
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;

            hls on;
            hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/hls;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            dash on;
            dash_path /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/dash;
            dash_fragment 15s;

        }
    }
}
http {
    server {
        listen 1936;
        location /status {
          stub_status on;
          allow all;
        }
        location /hls {
            # Serve HLS fragments
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /usr/local/nginx/html/stream;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        }

        location /dash {
            # Serve DASH fragments
            root /usr/local/nginx/html/stream;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        }
    }
}




tried several browsers and OSes, only Safari plays...

Your M3U8 is located at http:// but your website is from https://. You cannot mix server types.
